# Python/Scikit Learn with xgboost - ValueError: Can't handle mix of multiclass and continuous

Tags: python, python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn, xgboost

I'm new to XgBoost and regression analysis. I'm trying to find accuracy of a model by splitting the input data to train and test data.

Here's the code for the same:

```
dataset = numpy.genfromtxt('newtraindata.csv', delimiter=",")[:,:-1]
# split data into X and y
X = dataset[1:,0:72]
Y = dataset[1:,72]
print Y
# split data into train and test sets
seed = 7
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(X, Y,
                                    test_size=test_size, random_state=seed)    
# fit model on training data
model = xgboost.XGBClassifier()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
print(model.feature_importances_)
# make predictions for test data
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
predictions = [round(value) for value in y_pred]
# evaluate predictions
accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, predictions)
print("Accuracy: %.2f%%" % (accuracy * 100.0))
```

Error message returned is (line 25 is the line where *accuracy* is initialized):

> File "/home/ankit/Downloads/test.py", line 25, in 
>           accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, predictions)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/classification.py", line 172, in accuracy_score y_type, y_true, y_pred = _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/classification.py",
>   line 82, in _check_targets
>           "".format(type_true, type_pred))
>
> ValueError: Can't handle mix of continuous and multiclass
>   [Finished in 737.7s with exit code 1]

I had referred to the following link:

http://machinelearningmastery.com/evaluate-gradient-boosting-models-xgboost-python/

Comment: Can you show some examples of data from 'newtraindata.csv'?

Comment: 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 41.3521462563 548 856 856 6.7499311938 8036054027 208500
0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 41.3521462563 460 1262 1262 0 7715442176 181500
0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 41.3521462563 608 920 920 6.7638849086 8012006001 223500

Comment: the above data has 75 coloumns and 3 rows...the coloumns with 0s and 1s were originally non numeric attributes (categorical data) which has been converted into numeric type (by treating every category as a different coloumn http://machinelearningmastery.com/data-preparation-gradient-boosting-xgboost-python/ )
the remaing are numeric data

Comment: I know the data represented this way will be a little difficult to understand but any help will be highly appreciated :)

Comment: which column is your target variable? The dependent one that you want to predict?

Comment: The last one...
for each of the 3 rows the values of the last coloumn are 208500,
181500, 223500

Comment: it works fine with 75 coloums, but for dimensionality reduction, when I reduce the number of coloums containing numeric data, this error occurs

Comment: You say it has 75 columns, then why are you using index 72 in Y in your code?

Comment: It was working fine with 75 coloumns, it crashes when I use 72 coloumns, I need to reduce the number of coloumns for dimensionality reduction

Comment: If you are using 75 columns for training, that means that your target data is already included in your training data??

Comment: no...when i use 75 coloumns, i use 73 as index. Here the index 72 indicates I'm using 74 coloumns

Comment: You want to predict values (Regression) or classes (Classification). You are using XGBClassifier which classifies into given classes, not predict values.

Comment: This is what i think... You y_test has multiple_classes for a single data that's why its throwing you this error. Your y_test can not have multiple classes.. It should only have one single class... For example if your vector is 0010 then its okay because the first vector has only one class but is your vector is 0011 then its not because the seconda vector has two classes